# Missing placeholder for iOS SwiftUI TextField that inputs an Int

Tags: ios, swiftui, textfield, placeholder

I would like my iOS SwiftUI [TextField](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield) to display the placeholder "Enter an integer:", but the TextField displays 0 (the value of the var value).  The placeholder "Enter an integer:" does appear when the user deletes the 0.  How can I get the placeholder "Enter an integer:" to appear without making the user delete the 0 first?  Thank you in advance.  Xcode 11.6 on macOS Catalina 10.15.6.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value: Int = 0;
    @State private var text: String = "";
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(
                "Enter an integer:",
                value: $value,
                formatter: NumberFormatter(),
                onCommit: {self.text = "The product is \(2 * self.value).";}
            )
            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            
            Text(text)
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

We need to use formatter to show placeholder.

Our formatter should have `formatter.zeroSymbol  = ""`

```
let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .none
    formatter.zeroSymbol  = ""
    return formatter
}()
```

Using formatted:

```
TextField("Enter an integer:", value: $value, formatter: numberFormatter)
                    .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

To give placeholder with formatted `TextField` we need to use optional value holder.

Here is a fixed variant

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var value: Int?
    @State private var text: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(
                "Enter an integer:",
                value: $value,
                formatter: NumberFormatter(),
                onCommit: {self.text = "The product is \(2 * (self.value ?? 0)).";}
            )
            .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            Text(text)
        }
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
    }
}
```